# Search across a searchable field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way of searching across a tokenized field in Elasticsearch, so instead of returning the Elements indexed with my search, return a unique set of values that matched the best.

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "brand": [
        "word1",
        "another"
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "brand": [
        "word2",
        "word3",
        "yet_another"
    ]
}
```

So searching for `wo`, I would recieve a list of the words `word1`, `word2` and `word3` scored, of course.

Should I create a new index for that with these values?
Is there a way I can do that work by reusing the tokenization of my index?

Comment: To check which token are be present for a specific if run this : https://localhost:9200/index/_termvectors/3 more details here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference//current/docs-termvectors.html

Comment: I can't see the relation between both topics...